# how to use block in [nsthread detachNewThreadSelector]

Tags: ios, iphone, block, nsthread

I am using a block to download images in asynchronus call . I know how to use block in this way

```
 [self getimage:url block:^(UIImage *img) 
 {
    passblock(img);
 }];
```

but i dont know how to use block in this

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getimage:block:) toTarget:self withObject:string];
```

When this block is going to get callback in nsthread and how to handle it.

While doing this error that i am getting is bad access

```
 -(void)getimage:(id)strimage block:(imageblock)block
 {
  NSData *data=[NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:strimage]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:strurl];
 block(image);
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i tried pass two arguments also..but error remains same..

Answer (score 1):

The selector passed to detachNewThreadSelector must take only one argument.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:)

Answer (score 0):

Use GCD instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self getimage:url block:^(UIImage *img) {
        // You might want to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) here
        passblock(img);
    }];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //call your method here 
});
```

//in your method taking two arguments so detachNewThreadSelector passing only one argument .So better use above code and call your method with more number of arguments.